# Cas - Custom acceptable usage policy view

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

We are using [acceptable usage policy feature](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Webflow-Customization-AUP.html) to implement a requirement where the user has to accept some licence agreement before using our registered services.

We have implemented our custom `AcceptableUsagePolicyRepository` as proposed in the docs and the user is successfully redirected to acceptance policy view based on a condition.

At this point we need to customize this view, so we have added the generated `casAcceptableUsagePolicyView.html` in the overlay. Our goal is to present different terms text based on the user status(admin,typical user etc). Terms text and user status should be fetched from the database.

In a typical MVC application, a controller would be used to generate the java objects that would be finally rendered in the view.

**Question:** What is the recommended way of customizing the aforementioned view to dynamically render our content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: What is the recommended way of customizing the aforementioned view to dynamically render our content?

The easiest way, for the time being, would be to supply your own `AcceptableUsagePolicyVerifyAction` bean in a `@Configuration` class:

```java
    @Bean
    public Action acceptableUsagePolicyVerifyAction() {
        return new MyAcceptableUsagePolicyVerifyAction(...);
    }
```

In your own `MyAcceptableUsagePolicyVerifyAction`, you'd then fetch the user status/text you need and stuff it into the `RequestContext`'s relevant scope. In the `casAcceptableUsagePolicyView`, you can next write a bit of conditional logic to determine the relevant text based on the status found in the webflow scope.

To learn about how `@Configuration` classes work in general, you can:

- [Review this post](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuration-Management-Extensions.html)
- or [This post](https://apereo.github.io/2017/02/21/cas-autocfg-strategy/)
- or consult the documentation for Spring and/or Spring Boot.

Comment: Once again you saved my day!Thanks! However, I am now facing another issue. I have configured delegate authentication via pac4j engine for an external saml2 idp. After being authenticated and redirected back to cas protected service I am waiting to see my acceptance policy view  but this doesn't happen. Is there any configuration I am missing? Is it a bug or the acceptable usage policy applies only when authentication is performed on cas side?

Comment: That needs to be a separate question with a separate answer on a separate post :)